# How to create inside each directory a .txt file that is called as the directory with find command

Tags: command-line, find

I have to do it with the `find` command.
Now i have this:

```
sudo find /home/jesus/ -type d -exec touch {}/folder.txt \;
```

I want that inside each directory is created a file that starts with the same name as the directory and adds the name `folder.txt`

if I execute my command it creates the files with the correct names but not inside each directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `find` command, make use of `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, so the `touch`-command will be executed in the directory where `find` found a match. Use

```
find /path/to/directory -type d -execdir touch "{}"/folder.txt \;
```

or

```
find /path/to/directory -type d -execdir touch "{}"/"{}"folder.txt \;
```

depending on your desired file-name. The command you used does not produce the file-name you described in your question,so it's not really clear to me what you need here, but you can modify this examples to fulfill your needs. The first example matches the command you used, the second example matches your description.